# Is it possible to override a package-level function in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, overriding

I am trying to override a package-level function for my program.
Is this possible
Eg:

```
package com.abc.cde

class someClass(){
fun newMeth(){
.
.
}
}
fun functionToBeOverriden(){
}
```

Comment: How would you expect the override to work? Overriding comes from subclassing, and there is no class here. Can you please describe what you're trying to achieve?